# Capture output of command-not-found

Tags: command-line, bash, python, tty, functions

I am writing a bash function that I want to use the output of `command-not-found`, located on my system in `/usr/lib/command-not-found`. However, a simple $() does not suffice. The output goes straight to the terminal. This led me to believe that it wrote it to STDERR, but using `$(/usr/lib/command-not-found $command 2>&1)` still wrote to the terminal. Does it actually write to the TTY? If so, can I capture *that* output somehow? Is there a better way (an API maybe)?

Comment: `/usr/lib/command-not-found` on my system is a Python script, and definitely prints to `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this isn't working for you, but here's what does work on my machine...

As you can see below, I am able to save the output to a variable and then echo the contents of that variable.

```
user@machine:~$ out=$(/usr/lib/command-not-found abc 2>&1)
user@machine:~$ echo "$out"
No command 'abc' found, did you mean:
 Command 'cbc' from package 'coinor-cbc' (universe)
 Command 'nbc' from package 'nbc' (universe)
 Command 'axc' from package 'afnix' (universe)
 Command 'bc' from package 'bc' (main)
 Command 'atc' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
 Command 'ajc' from package 'aspectj' (universe)
 Command 'abe' from package 'abe' (universe)
 Command 'ab' from package 'apache2-utils' (main)
 Command 'asc' from package 'asc' (universe)
 Command 'aec' from package 'libaec-tools' (universe)
 Command 'arc' from package 'arcanist' (universe)
 Command 'arc' from package 'arc' (universe)
 Command 'abx' from package 'abx' (universe)
 Command 'alc' from package 'amule-utils-gui' (universe)
 Command 'ac' from package 'acct' (main)
abc: command not found
```

Comment: Works for me too.